# How to verify if the kalman gain matrix K is working properly?

Tags: control-theory, estimation, optimal-control, linear-control, kalman-filter

If I have a state space model.

$$x(k + 1) = Ax(k) + Bu(k)$$
$$y(k) = Cx(k) + Du(k)$$

And a kalman gain matrix $K$. Then, how do I know if the kalman gain matrix $K$ is properly designed for my state space model?

I know that I can use my kalman gain matrix $K$ as an observer.

$$\hat x(k + 1) = A\hat x(k) + Bu(k) + Ke(k)$$
$$\hat y(k) = C\hat x(k) + Du(k)$$

Where $e(k) = y(k) - \hat y(k)$ is a gaussian white noise with zero mean.

**Question:**

Assuming that I have the model of the system and I know the noise $e(k)$ and the input $u(k)$. Can I just simulate a regular state space model like this

$$\hat x(k + 1) = A\hat x(k) + \begin{bmatrix}
B & K 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
u(k) \\
e(k)
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\hat y(k) = C\hat x(k) + Du(k)$$

And then measure how "clean" $\hat y(k)$ compared to $y(k)$?

Or is there any theoretical proof I can to to verify if the $K$ matrix is OK?

**Update:**

My question is about checking if the generated kalman gain matrix $K$ is "OK". What I mean by that, is that I want to check its accuracy. But I don't know how to specify the accuracy. I want the best filtering as possible, but I cannot specify the best filtering due to lack of something to refere to.

If I would describe my kalman filter with words, then a good estimation results looks like this. Here we have a very noisy sensor and the estimation is going to follow the original coordinate. The sum of all square errors is going to be as small as possible

$$J_{\text{min}} = \sum(\hat y - y_{\text{original coordinate}})^2 $$

Question remains: How can I test this condition if I have

- The model
- Kalman filter gain matrix $K$
- Noise vector $e$
- Trajectory $y$
- Noisy trajectory $y_n$
- Input signal $u$

[image]

Comment: Can you define "Kalman gain matrix"? Also "clean" and "OK".

Comment: @KBS I cannot specify a specific number, because I don't know what "good" or "clean" or "OK" is. I just want to learn that if I specify a specific "number". How can I check with my Kalman Filter how well correct that kalman filter is compared to that number? Let's say I want to accuracy 90%. Can I analyse the kalman filter's accuracy?

Comment: It does not really clarify things. Please update your question with more details and clearly explain the context and what you want to do with words.

Comment: @KBS Yes. I will..

Comment: @KBS done....Updated

Comment: @KBS Please remove the minus down vote.

Comment: Why would $e(k) = y(k) - \hat y(k)$ be a Gaussian white noise with zero mean? I suppose also that the Kalman gain is that of the Kalman filter. Your edits have not made your problem clearer.

Comment: @KBS Because I $y(k)$ is the real measurement. $\hat y(k)$ is the estimated state.

Comment: @KBS Or is this not possible to check if the error?

Comment: Sorry, but not wasting my time answering unclear questions. Please improve your post. Your last question does not make any sense. You will have to learn to answer your own questions by yourself and stop systematically asking here. You are clearly abusing it.

Comment: General principle: There are often explicit expressions for the mean square error at each time step for the Kalman filter. So you can run a million independent test cases, each over 20 slots, and plot the resulting simulated MSE in each slot as compared to the exact analytical value.  This will help to know if you have any typos or bugs in your program.  Sometimes you may inadvertently be using a parameter associated with time $t-1$ at time $t$.

Comment: @KBS stop being so rude and become better. You don't gain anything with that attitude. Just wasting your time at stackexchange. Time for you to take a break, or learn to know other people.

Comment: @Michael Can I use 'lsim' for that?

Comment: I don't know lsim (I assume it is software).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kindly think that you're not asking the right question.
The Kalman gain matrix $K$ is a multiplication of three matrices, so if you multiply them correctly (which is trivial) it's correct by definition:
$$
K_k = \hat{P}_k H_k S_k^{-1},
$$
where

- $\hat{P}_k = F_k P_{k-1} F_k^T + Q_k$ is the predicted covariance matrix of the state,
- $H_k$ is the observation model, and
- $S_k = H_k \hat{P}_k H_k^T + R_k$ is the covariance of the innovation.

Now, what you want to know is if these three elements are correct.
I recommend carefully reading the [wiki KF page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter), which is very helpful imo.

In short:

1. It is critical that you make sure that your matrices $F$, $B$ and $H$ correctly represent your system. They are usually derived analytically for each particular application.
2. Please bear in mind that KF applications usually need  a non-trivial step of fine tuning the covariance matrices for the system model and the sensor, $Q$ and $R$. The accuracy of the filter output is **greatly influenced** by their accuracies.